# Representations of the automorphism group of graphs via spectral graphs theory

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, graph-theory

Given a (simple) graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{1,...,n\}$ and let $A$ be its adjacency matrix.

I am interested in the representation theory (over $\Bbb R$) of the automorphism group $\def\Aut{\mathrm{Aut}}\Aut(G)$. One way to generate such representations is via spectral graph theory. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the associated eigenspace $\def\Eig{\mathrm{Eig}}\Eig_\lambda(G)$, then the *rows* of the matrix

$$U:=\begin{pmatrix}
| & & |\\
e_1 & \cdots & e_m \\
| & & |
\end{pmatrix}$$

can be interpreted as the positions $v_i\in\Bbb R^m,i=1,...,n$ of the vertices of $G$ in a graph embedding. What is special about this embedding is, that it realizes all the symmetries of $G$. This means, for each automorphism $\phi\in\Aut(G)$, there is a linear map $M_\phi\in\mathrm{GL}(m,\Bbb R)$ with $v_{\phi(i)}=M_\phi v_i$. This gives a real representation $\Aut(G)\to\mathrm{GL}(m,\Bbb R),\phi\mapsto M_\phi$.

My questions are:

> Was this construction of real representations of $\Aut(G)$ already studied somewhere in the literature?

and especially:

> When are these respresentations (real) *irreducible*?

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/89099/108884) mentions graphs with trivial symmetry group but large eigenspaces, which therefore cannot provide irreducible representations. However, I am interested in graphs with a lot of symmetries, especially arc-transitive graphs. In all the cases I studied, all the representations turned out to be irreducible.

---

**Update**

- A similar question was asked on [Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83939/415941) and received an interesting answer from C. Godsil. Especially the last parenthesized sentence leaves space for an interesting counter-example.
- The searchable terminology seems to be "reducible/irreducible eigenspaces of graphs". At least this lead me to the following paper

  [G. Berkolaiko, W. Liu: Eigenspaces of Symmetric Graphs are not Typically Irreducible (2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01653.pdf)

  However, I am not aware of a direct connection to the problem stated here, partially because the paper's terminology is not very familiar to me, yet.

Comment: not all $\lambda$'s lead to a meaningful embedding. E.g. if the graph is regular then the maximal eigenvalue has multiplicity 1...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I admit: "embedding" is usually used for injective maps. Here I mean just any mapping $V\to\Bbb R^d$, injective or not. The non-injective ones then correspond to non-faithful representations. The largest eigenvalue (in a connected regular graph) will always give the trivial representation $\phi\to\mathrm{id}$ (and thats totally meaningful).

Comment: How does such a trivial representation "realise all the symmetries of $G$" ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik In the sense as explained in the post: for every automorphism $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ there is an orthogonal map $M_\phi\in\mathrm{GL}(m,\Bbb R)$ with $M_\phi v_i=v_{\phi(i)}$. Of course, the injective realizations are the more interesting ones, but the others fit the definition and might carry interesting information about the graph. It's also less relevant for the question, as a source which only discussed the faithful ones would be interesting too.

Comment: OK, but "realises all the symmetries of G" reads like plain English for "provides a faithful representation of Aut(G)", isn't it?

Comment: I agree w/ Dima. I think "Admits all the automorphisms of $G$" might be better terminology than "realizes".

Answer (score 2):

Recently I found an arc-transitive graph (and then many more) for which some eigenspaces are reducible, something that I believed might not occure.

The example is the [Shrikhande graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrikhande_graph), a strongly regular graph with parameters $(16,6,2,2)$.

The spectrum consists of eigenvalues $6^1, -2^6, 2^9$ (multiplicities in the exponent), where only the eigenspace of $2$ is reducible. I cannot tell you how exactly the eigenspace decomposes since my knowledge about this stems from computing the characters and the Frobenius-Schur indicator as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2938095/415941).

There are other examples: e.g. $C_{10}\times C_{10}$ and some circulant graphs that have *one* suspiciously large eigenspace that decomposes. I have not investigated for what parameters these reducible eigenspaces occure, I just know that they are *not always* present.

What is interesting though, is, that the eigenspace to the second largest eigenvalue seems to be always irreducible. This is interesting since this eigenspace is related to the [*algebraic connectivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity) and is a central object of my research. I will have to investigate whether this is always true.

---

**Update**

Even the eigenspace of the second-largest eigenvalue does not have to be irreducible. I found some examples by computing Frobenius-Schur indicators for various arc-transitive graphs. However, counter-examples seem to be rare.