# Smallest strongly regular graph whose automorphism group is not vertex transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, automorphism-groups

I'm looking for a small strongly regular graph whose automorphism group is not vertex-transitive.

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/115598/75171/) to a different question shows that the Chang graphs on 28 vertices are such graphs.  Is there an example on less vertices?

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129397/rigid-strongly-regular-graphs?rq=1

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks a lot for the link.  So this gets me an example of 25 vertices, and no nontrivial automorphisms.  Still wondering if non-vertex transitive can be even smaller...

Comment: A minor comment: Problem 20c in Biggs "Algebraic Graph Theory" 2nd Ed. shows a simple construction of a strongly regular graph on 26 vertices that is not vertex-transitive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no smaller example.

Various places, including Andries Brouwer's list of parameters and existence for small SRGS (http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html) show that there are only a handful of parameter sets to check.

Those with fewer than 25 vertices can almost be checked by hand as they fall into a few families (Paley graphs) or are well-known individual graphs (e.g Clebsch graph).

For the parameter set  $(25, 12, 5, 6)$ there are exactly $15$ graphs and they have automorphism groups of orders $1$ (twice), $2$ (four times), $3$ (twice), $6$ (four times), $72$ (twice) and $600$.